# How do I get CatBoost get_object_importance to work with AUC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I replicated the example [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/tutorials/advanced_tutorials/catboost_object_importance_tutorial.ipynb).

The example tries to improve RMSE (lower->better).

My limited understanding is that CatBoost will try to minimize LogLoss under the hood. In this example lower LogLoss seems to correlate to lower RMSE.

```
RMSE on validation datset when 0 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.25915746122622113
RMSE on validation datset when 250 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.25601149050939825
RMSE on validation datset when 500 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.25158044983631966
RMSE on validation datset when 750 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.24570533776587475
RMSE on validation datset when 1000 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.24171376432589384
RMSE on validation datset when 1250 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.23716221792112202
RMSE on validation datset when 1500 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.23352830055657348
RMSE on validation datset when 1750 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.23035731488436903
RMSE on validation datset when 2000 harmful objects from train are dropped: 0.2275943109556251
```

Besides observing RMSE with `cb.eval_metrics(validation_pool, ['RMSE'])['RMSE'][-1]`, the example doesn't really use RMSE as a custom loss function.

```
cb = CatBoost({'iterations': 100, 'verbose': False, 'random_seed': 42})
print(cb.eval_metrics(validation_pool, ['RMSE'])['RMSE'][-1])
```

In my case I have a binary classification problem and I want to maximize AUC. 
I'm not sure if I should just leave the code as is, and hope that lower logloss correlates to higher AUC (it doesn't), or if I need to set this up differently, perhaps using AUC as a custom loss/eval_metric function and then flipping `importance_values_sign` from 'Positive' to 'Negative'.

Comment: RMSE and AUC measures are not compatible; the former applies only to regression settings, while the latter only to classification ones

Answer (score 1):

In case of `loss_function='RMSE'`, CatBoost try to minimize `RMSE` loss function, not `Logloss`. `RMSE` is the default CatBoost loss function.

CatBoost evaluates `Logloss` using formula from [this](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/loss-functions-docpage/) page. Therefore, lower `Logloss` correlates to higher `AUC`.

So, you just need to replace

`cb = CatBoost({'iterations': 100, 'verbose': False, 'random_seed': 42})`

with

`cb = CatBoost({'loss_function': 'Logloss', 'iterations': 100, 'verbose': False, 'random_seed': 42})`

And observe not for `RMSE`, but for `AUC`.